# Question regarding an Escherichia coli reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, bioinorganic-chemistry

With respect to this link
http://www.biocyc.org/ECOLI/NEW-IMAGE?type=REACTION&object=RXN-14479 
Here the enzyme is mentioned and the two reacting compounds. Now , my question is 
 
1. When these two compounds react, do they initially get attached to the enzyme before reaction?
2.If they Do both these compounds get attached to the enzyme, what is such an interaction called? Protein compound interaction??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, enterochelin esterase (Fes) utilizes an [Alpha/Beta hydrolase](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/entry/IPR029058) fold to catalyze it's reactions, which means there's a triad of catalytic amino acid side chains. Where Fes differs from other proteins in the pathway is an amino terminal lid domain which confers specificity to the substrates of Fes ([(1)](https://walsh.med.harvard.edu/pubs/PDFs_2/IroE_structure.pdf) dictates this forms a deep pocket in the protein). I'm having trouble finding the exact catalytic amino acids, but homology modeling between IroE and Fes from the same source shows this may be a triad of Glu, His and Ser. If we kind of visualize what a catalytic triad's mechanism looks like, and the following image is a generic lipase/esterase catalytic site,

[image]

A sort of **transition state** is formed between the target molecule and the serine, where the water reacts with help from the asp/glu and histidine to catalyze the hydrolysis. You'd just call it protein-ligand interactions.

Comment: Okay now I found this article in wikipaedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand , this has got a list of ligands... but the reaction I provided, doesnt contain the list of ligands as mentioned in wikipaedia, then how is it called a protein ligand interaction? Is it because the compound may contain a ligand group which binds to the protein which is why you called it protein ligand binding?

Comment: In biochemistry, we'd refer to the ligand as anything that forms a complex with the protein. That includes inhibitors, substrates, etc. The ligand that binds to the active site of the protein is it's **substrate**, and the following [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_(biochemistry)) page explicates ligands from a biochemical perspective.